# How to re-attach toilet paper holder post back onto wall

Tags: bathroom, screws

wondering if any of you have suggestions on how to screw back into the wall one of the posts holding a roller for toilet paper which has recently come off.

[image]

The piece of metal you see on the wall should hook onto one end of the post (see below) in some way

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are missing a hook or set screw. If there is a hole, get a set screw that will thread into it, place the holder back on the bracket and tighten it to hold. Make sure your bracket is secure and tight so the holder end doesn't turn on the wall.

Comment: All of these that I know of have a single screw and yours is still there. Presumably the end opposite the screw is a fixed hook. Orient the bracket on the wall (horizontal or vertical as required), and tighten it in place. Retract the point of the set screw completely inside the threaded area, place the holder over the bracket, and tighten the set screw to secure it to the bracket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your photo of the "post" you can see a screw (called a "grub screw" in the UK or a "set screw" in the US, if you want the terminology). You need a small screwdriver to loosen off this screw. The post will then fit back over the wall bracket, and you tighten up the grub screw to reconnect the post to the wall.

Comment: Over here (USA) it's usually called a 'set screw.'   No big deal- it's clear what job it does.

Comment: @user2327969 - Do feel free to upvote any helpful answers, and give the green tick to the best one. As well as giving people rep, this also earns you rep and helps future users by letting them know what worked. Comments are considered less permanent than answers and votes.